# Is it possible to move names and parts separately in board edit mode in Eagle?

Tags: eaglecad

Most factory-created PCBs I have seen has part names aligned very accurate, without any overlap, without placing under the SMD devices, and so on.

My question is - can I move part names separately from parts itself using `Eagle` (7.1.0 if that matters)? I know I can open library and edit related package, but

- That would be too long for each part;
- I'll end up with conflicts;

Also there is an option to create labels using `Text` tool and place them on `tNames/bNames` layer, but that is too long too. Is there a faster way to do it? Or, maybe my approach is not the best one? The only thing I care about is final result.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it's called the `Smash` feature. Select `Smash` from the toolbar, click on the part, and the name and value labels can be moved and rotated independently from the part itself (with their own `origin`).

When moving the name or value labels after smashing, a helpful line appears that shows to which part the label belongs. When moving or rotating the part itself, the name and value labels will move and rotate the same relative amount so they don't become visually disassociated from the part.

Comment: That's what happens when you're newbie with the tool :D I have never used `Smash` before, thanks :)